# c++ array sorting with some specifications

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm using C++. Using sort from STL is allowed.

I have an array of **int**, like this :

```
1 4 1 5 145 345 14 4
```

The numbers are stored in a **char*** (i read them from a binary file, 4 bytes per numbers)

I want to do two things with this array :

1. swap each number with the one after that

   4 1 5 1 345 145 4 14
2. sort it by group of 2

   4 1 4 14 5 1 345 145

---

I could code it step by step, but it wouldn't be efficient. What I'm looking for is speed. O(n log n) would be great.

Also, this array can be bigger than 500MB, so memory usage is an issue.

---

My first idea was to sort the array starting from the end (to swap the numbers 2 by 2) and treating it as a **long*** (to force the sorting to take 2 int each time). But I couldn't manage to code it, and I'm not even sure it would work.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks for your help : )

Comment: I don't get your sort by group of 2.

Comment: 1/ swap each number with the one after that
doing that would just move the first number to the end right?

Comment: Your sort-by-two is easy enough with an `int [][2]` and a block sorter like `qsort()`. But I'm still stuck way back on the "those numbers are stored in a char* " announcement. Are you saying they are *not* in native `int` form? (and no, your proposal for a `long*` cast will most-assuredly *not* work, especially since most implementations have a `long` and `int` of the same bit depth).

Comment: seems you should be able to use the stl sort function with your own compare that only uses the first element of each pair.

Comment: Also, when you say "this array can be bigger than 500MB" do you mean the data size is 500MB (approx 131072000 `int` values), or there can be 524288000 or more `int` values (which on a 32bit `int` system would comprise over 2gB of data). ?

Comment: @WhozCraig haha, i think he doesn't mean it literally.  it's just probably meant to mean that it can be very very big.  i guess 2gb isn't really that big nowadays anyway.  although at that size, you can do radix sort :p  only 2 gig positive ints.

Comment: @WhozCraig the array come from reading a binary file (of ints) byte by byte. I could just cast it into int* and it wouldn't change anything. I guess I could translate it into something else if necessary (like int[][2]), but I would prefer not to. especially since I need a char* for what comes after that. And yes, data size is around 500MB.

Comment: so... you *do* have them in `int` form? or is this whole thing just sitting in a lord-knows-what-endian-ness `unsigned char` linear backdrop of what is supposed to be 32bit ints?

Comment: "lord-knows-what-endian-ness unsigned char linear backdrop of what is supposed to be 32bit ints" yes. little endian

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t get it: is the array of type `int` or type `char*`? What does the array declaration look like?

Comment: @Konrad, something like :
`char *data = new char[length];` and  
`read(file,data,length);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most memory efficient layout I could come up with. Obviously the vector I'm using would be replaced by the data blob you're using, assuming endian-ness is all handled well enough. The premise of the code below is simple.

1. Generate 1024 random values in pairs, each pair consisting of the first number between 1 and 500, the second number between 1 and 50.
2. Iterate the entire list, flipping all even-index values with their following odd-index brethren.
3. Send the entire thing to `std::qsort` with an item width of **two** (2) `int32_t` values and a count of half the original vector.
4. The comparator function simply sorts on the immediate value first, and on the second value if the first is equal.

The sample below does this for 1024 items. I've tested it without output for 134217728 items (exactly 536870912 bytes) and the results were pretty impressive for a measly macbook air laptop, about 15 seconds, only about 10 of that on the actual sort. What is ideally most important is **no additional memory allocation is required beyond the data vector.** Yes, to the purists, I do use call-stack space, but only because q-sort does.

I hope you get something out of it.

Note: I only show the first part of the output, but I hope it shows what you're looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>


// a most-wacked-out random generator. every other call will
//  pull from a rand modulo either the first, or second template
//  parameter, in alternation.
template<int N,int M>
struct randN
{
    int i = 0;
    int32_t operator ()()
    {
        i = (i+1)%2;
        return (i ? rand() % N : rand() % M) + 1;
    }
};

// compare to integer values by address.
int pair_cmp(const void* arg1, const void* arg2)
{
    const int32_t *left = (const int32_t*)arg1;
    const int32_t *right = (const int32_t *)arg2;
    return (left[0] == right[0]) ? left[1] - right[1] : left[0] - right[0];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // a crapload of int values
    static const size_t N = 1024;

    // seed rand()
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    // get a huge array of random crap from 1..50
    vector<int32_t> data;
    data.reserve(N);
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(data), N, randN<500,50>());

    // flip all the values
    for (size_t i=0;i<data.size();i+=2)
    {
        int32_t tmp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[i+1];
        data[i+1] = tmp;
    }

    // now sort in pairs. using qsort only because it lends itself
    //  *very* nicely to performing block-based sorting.
    std::qsort(&data[0], data.size()/2, sizeof(data[0])*2, pair_cmp);
    cout << "After sorting..." << endl;
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<int32_t>(cout,"\n"));
    cout << endl << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
After sorting...
1
69
1
83
1
198
1
343
1
367
2
12
2
30
2
135
2
169
2
185
2
284
2
323
2
325
2
347
2
367
2
373
2
382
2
422
2
492
3
286
3
321
3
364
3
377
3
400
3
418
3
441
4
24
4
97
4
153
4
210
4
224
4
250
4
354
4
356
4
386
4
430
5
14
5
26
5
95
5
145
5
302
5
379
5
435
5
436
5
499
6
67
6
104
6
135
6
164
6
179
6
310
6
321
6
399
6
409
6
425
6
467
6
496
7
18
7
65
7
71
7
84
7
116
7
201
7
242
7
251
7
256
7
324
7
325
7
485
8
52
8
93
8
156
8
193
8
285
8
307
8
410
8
456
8
471
9
27
9
116
9
137
9
143
9
190
9
190
9
293
9
419
9
453
```

Comment: Well unfortunately OP has now clarified that they meant `char*` all along. Not `std::vector<int>`, not `std::vector<char*>`, but plain `char*`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph with which comment? I see him loading a char buffer from the file with a raw read, but where does he disavow his original claim the file is in binary 32-little-endian format? Is there somewhere up there he now claims these are all ascii chars? The vector in the code above is only so I have something to demonstrate the algorithm with, I expect the OP to bring an `int*` to the table.

Comment: No, it’s 32 bit LE. But your code still assumes `std::vector<int32_t>` and OP wants to do it in-place (\*evil cackle\*).

Comment: And how, using the algorithm above, is that not possible? I only used a vector to demonstrate the algorithm. I could always run up and replace it with a big-ol-malloc, I suppose. Do you think it warranted that I do so? I usually prefer to post runnable code that *demonstrates* the solution, but perhaps not in this case. I think you're right. maybe just a function is all that is needed and let him figure out the setup.

Comment: But that’s not valid C++ (UB and all that). ;-) But yeah, I see your point (and you got the obligatory upboat).

Comment: UB ? Ah you mean he spits in the face of strict aliasing. yeah. I concur. pretty damn ugly. ok. i'll leave it. thanks for the upvote, btw.

Comment: thanks, this work great. Too bad we can't get around flipping all the values first.

Comment: @user1278743 you don't *have* to flip the values to accommodate the sort. You could just as easily skip the flip and change the comparator to sort by val[1] dominantly, and val[0] if the val[1] values are equal. Of course, your code using the sorted output would also need to know that your first "value" is actually in val[1], the second in val[0] as well, but the point is flipping the values is *not* required to perform the same sort; just change the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

With some additional constraints on both your input and your platform, you can probably use an approach like the one you are thinking of. These constraints would include

- Your input contains only positive numbers (i.e. can be treated as unsigned)
- Your platform provides `uint8_t` and `uint64_t` in `<cstdint>`
- You address a single platform with known endianness.

In that case you can divide your input into groups of 8 bytes, do some byte shuffling to arrange each groups as one `uint64_t` with the "first" number from the input in the lower-valued half and run `std::sort` on the resulting array. Depending on endianness you may need to do more byte shuffling to rearrange each sorted 8-byte group as a pair of uint32_t in the expected order.

If you *can't code this* on your own, I'd strongly advise you not to take this approach.

A better and more portable approach (you have some inherent non-portability by starting from a not clearly specified binary file format), would be:

```
std::vector<int> swap_and_sort_int_pairs(const unsigned char buffer[], size_t buflen) {
   const size_t intsz = sizeof(int);
   // We have to assume that the binary format in buffer is compatible with our int representation
   // we also require an even number of integers
   assert(buflen % (2*intsz) == 0);

   // load pairwise
   std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > pairs;
   pairs.reserve(buflen/(2*intsz));
   for (const unsigned char* bufp=buffer; bufp<buffer+buflen; bufp+= 2*intsz) {
      // It would be better to have a more portable binary -> int conversion
      int first_value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(bufp);
      int second_value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(bufp + intsz);
      // swap each pair here
      pairs.emplace_back( second_value, firstvalue );
   }
   // less<pair<..>> does lexicographical ordering, which is what you are looking ofr
   std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());

   // convert back to linear vector 
   std::vector<int> result;
   result.reserve(2*pairs.size());
   for (auto& entry : pairs) {
      result.push_back(entry.first);
      result.push_back(entry.second);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Both the inital parse/swap pass (which you need anyway) and the final conversion are O(N), so the total complexity is still (O(N log(N)).

If you can continue to work with pairs, you can save the final conversion. The other way to save that conversion would be to use a hand-coded sort with two-int strides and two-int swap: much more work - and possibly still hard to get as efficient as a well-tuned library sort.

Comment: Depending on the way you read your buffer, you can combine the initial parse/swap pass directly with your I/O.

Comment: This is how I’d do it (with the caveat you mentioned about UB in `reinterpret_cast`).

Comment: Thanks for the code, I chose to accept WhozCraig's answer because it is much more memory efficient (even though your solution is slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing at a time. First, give your data some *struct*ure. It seems that each 8 byte form a unit of the
form

```
struct unit {
    int key;
    int value;
}
```

If the endianness is right, you can do this in O(1) with a reinterpret_cast. If it isn't, you'll have to live with a O(n) conversion effort. Both vanish compared to the O(n log n) search effort.

When you have an array of these units, you can use std::sort like:

```
bool compare_units(const unit& a, const unit& b) {
    return a.key < b.key;
}

std::sort(array, length, compare_units);
```

The key to this solution is that you do the "swapping" and byte-interpretation first and then do the sorting.

Comment: This would require me to go through all the data to store it into a struct. Speed is my first priority. It would also double the memory usage (at least before freeing my original array).

Comment: using `std::pair<int, int>` instead of your own struct removes the necessity of defining a comparator. @user1278743 store the data directly into the array of pairs.

Comment: @user1278743: You can either use reinterpret_cast<> with a careful struct layout (be sure to unit-test that) or you can do the right thing and struct the data while reading the file instead of passing around a totally unstructured char pointer. The first solution is in O(1), the second in O(n), **and both will be much faster than an O(n log n) sort**. So, forget about the speed impact.

Comment: @stefan: Using a tuple has the disadvantage of not assigning any meaning to the fields. Having an explicit comparator is not much effort and is well worth the effort of having meaningful member names.

Comment: @thiton Sure, but you don't get such horrible comparators which completely ignore the second value, which could result in the unwanted sorting (4,14), (4, 1),.. in the example of OP.

Comment: @thiton That’s an overrated benefit in this case: the fields have no intrinsic meaning, so don’t invent one. With C++11 you should really get used to using tuples more often. Not everywhere, mind you – but more often.

Comment: fwiw, `std::pair`s built-in `operator <()` does *exactly* what the OP needs (sort by `first` unless they're equal, then sort by `second`).